# How to calculate the difference between two UTC values

Tags: bash

I am trying to get the difference (in days) from two UTC values:

```
export CURRENT_TIME=`date -u %FT%Z`
export START_TIME=`2018-02-26T04:46:20Z`
```

Can I subtract them directly or do I need to convert them before?

Comment: You need to convert into epoch seconds values. For example `date -u -d "$START_TIME" +%s`

Answer (score 2):

The diff:

```
diff=$(( $(date --date="$CURRENT_TIME" +%s) - $(date --date="$START_TIME" +%s) ))
```

also, for CURRENT_TIME I think you mean

```
export CURRENT_TIME=$(date -u +'%FT%T%Z')
```